# Store date and system date comparison in php

Tags: php

I have store date in dd-mm-yy and I am getting system date by date(d.m.y).
So I have to compare this two values and have to find out which one is greater.
The following code is not working correctly if I change the end date. I need to compare in Javascript also.
I have written this

```
$day=date("d");
$month=date("m");
$year=date("y");
$year="20".$year;

$enddate='31-11-2011';
$end=explode("-",$enddate);
$end_day=$end[0];
$end_month=$end[1];
$end_year=$end[2];
$allow=0;
if($year<=$end_year)
{
 if($month<=$end_month)
 {
   if($day<=$end_day)
   {
    $allow=1;
   }
   else
   {
    $allow=0;
   }
 }
 else
 {
 $allow=0;
 }
}
else
{
 $allow=0;
}

if($allow==0)
{
 echo "expired";
}
else
{
 echo "Active";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this:

```
$today = strtotime(date("d") . "/" . date("m") . "/20" . date("y") . " 00:00:00");
$toCompare = strtotime("31/11/2011 00:00:00");
if($today == $toCompare)
{
 //Same
}
else
{
 //Different
}
```

The two functions that are used are [strototime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and time().

Comment: Your solution will be valid only in ONE second each day at 00:00:00

Comment: Ah.  I didn't realize that he wanted to just know if the day was the same.  Will edit my answer now.

Comment: thanks man it works,can you suggest me incase of javascript which function shall i use

Comment: Here is a Javascript function for strototime:  http://caioariede.com/arquivos/strtotime.js

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simplier way to compare two dates:

```
$currentDate = Date ( 'm-d-Y' ); // Y will return year in XXXX format not like y which returns year in XX format
$endDate = '31-11-2011';

if ( StrToTime ( $currentDate ) > StrToTime ( $endDate ) ) {
  // current date is bigger
} else {
  // end date is bigger
}
```

The [StrToTime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime) function converts a string representation of a date to a UNIX timestamp which is a integer.

Comment: thanks man it works,can you suggest me incase of javascript which function shall i use